# Non-sudo user command line tools

Tags: command-line, server

I’ve got some non-sudo users and certain command line tools don’t work for them – but they do in other Linux OS.

For example, pressing up would normally give you your last used command, and pressing tab would complete the rest of a directory or file name. Neither of these work for non-sudo users.

I don’t want to give  them sudo access, but I’ve used them successfully in CentOS and was wondering if similar permissions where possible in Ubuntu Server?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a sudo issue, but more related to the shell they are using. What shell do the users use? Are they working as other users is the `$HOME` writable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sudo.

First, check which shell your users are using. Not every shell supports the arrows for history. Bash, the default shell, does, however.

If that fails, check the relevant shell's configuration files, both of the users and the system files. See if there's anything there to disable the feature.